# C# LINQ - How to get distinct record?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have an SQL table like this:
[image]

How can I get the max value for each distinct Key column?

My expected result is:
[image]

Comment: Below query in answer does not server the purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tableName>.GroupBy(k => k.key)
           .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(v => v.value)
           .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: It works like a charm! But it won't allow me to use the .First() command, instead I used .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Thanks!  I typically use .FirstOrDefault().  Glad it helped.  Using .First() also assumes there will be at least 1 item in each group or will throw an error. Appreciate your clean and concise question.  Most of the time folks are too vague or write a novel to explain what they are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Let say I have Employee class with ID and Age. Below query should return you result in expected format. Basically query going to group items by Id and return max value from each group.

```
List<Empployee> lst = new List<Empployee>();

            lst.GroupBy(g => g.ID).ToList().ForEach(g =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key:{g.Key} and Value:{g.Max(m => m.Age)}");
            });

public class Empployee
        {
           public int ID { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the answer which I have marked is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value).Take(1));
```

It's best to get into a habit of doing a `SelectMany`/`Take(1)` combination over the `Select`/`First()` as the former is robust to adding a `Where` clause and the latter is not.